# Не получается создать переменную в jinja

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, jinja

Пишу сайт на `django`. Столкнулся с проблемой, что не могу создать переменную в шаблоне. Например вот такой код:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% set a = '7' %}
    {{ a }}
</body>
</html>
```

выдает ошибку `Invalid block tag on line 8: 'set'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чувствую себя совсем тупым, но ответ найти не могу

Comment: Это не jinja, в Django не используется jinja, а в шаблонизаторе Django создавать переменные невозможно

Comment: @andreymal И правда) почему-то много где шаблонизатор django называют jinja... Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Хотя я в каком-то смысле немножко приврал, в шаблонизаторе django есть [with](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#with), но это не совсем эквивалентно созданию переменных

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо, помогло)

Answer (score 2):

Как подсказал @andreymal в комментариях шаблонизатор django и шаблонизатор jinja это оказывается разные вещи. В шаблонизаторе django нельзя создавать переменные.